# What to use in order to run code once screen is tapped?

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

I am working on a game in Xcode where an object is bouncing back and forth across the screen. I need to run the code to stop the object from moving once the user taps anywhere on the screen. I don't want to use a button although I could. I am new to this and don't understand what I need to use in order to run some code once the user taps the screen. Could you please tell me what to use and explain what it does.

code:

```
#import "Game.h"

@interface Game ()

@end


@implementation Game

-(IBAction)Play:(id)sender{

   ShakeTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.01 target:self selector:@selector(Shake) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

     Play.hidden = YES;}

-(void)Shake{
    CABasicAnimation *shake = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    [shake setDuration:1];
    [shake setRepeatCount:INFINITY];
    [shake setAutoreverses:YES];
    [shake setFromValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:
                         CGPointMake(Piece.center.x - 5,Piece.center.y)]];
    [shake setToValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:
                       CGPointMake(Piece.center.x + 300, Piece.center.y)]];
    [Piece.layer addAnimation:shake forKey:@"position"];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *Taps= [[  UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                  initWithTarget:self action: @selector(Shoot)];
   Taps.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;

    Taps.numberOfTouchesRequired =1;

    [self. addGestureRecognizer:Taps];
}

-(void)Shoot{
    [ShakeTimer invalidate];

}

- (void)viewDidLoad{
    Leave.hidden = YES;}

-(void)GameOver{
    Leave.hidden = NO;
    [PieceMovement invalidate];
    }
@end
```

Comment: you have to use uigesture for that

Comment: Ok ill research that.

Answer (score 0):

These are the methods you may override in a UIView subclass:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a UITapGestureRecognizer.  Initialize one using `[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];`

This is what the handling method would look like

```
- (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        // handling code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use UITapGestureRecognizer or override UIViewController's touchesBegan( _: _:),touchedMoved( _: _:)... to write your own touch handling logic.

A gesture recognizer bind to a view and function on it only while the touchesBegan(_: _:) methods can always be triggered when the view user touched is in the responder chain.

A kind of gesture recognizer only monitor the gesture behavior what it define(tap,long press...).

Comment: Ok. I have researched it and watched a few tutorials but am still struggling. I am gonna post my code above for you to look at. The app runs but once I tap the screen nothing happens. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I guess the button is hitted(you can add a breakpoint to check it), the reason of following functions is not triggered, is because you timer. A NSTimer object should be added to a NSRunLoop object, typical the singleton of NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop()